# Plot pvalue information for mean comparisons by grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I've put together a plot to view groups separately but now want to include significance levels for mean pairwise comparison in the plot. While I can do the comparison outside of the plot I'm wondering what the most efficient way of including the comparison in the plot would be?

Current Plot

```
library(tidyverse)

dsub <- diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 10000), ]

dsub <- dsub %>%
  filter(clarity %in% c('VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2'))

ggplot(dsub, aes(x = cut, y = carat, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_point(pch = 21, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

Now I want to add the comparisons **within each level** of the `cut` variable **between all levels** of the `clarity` variable. I prefer using `ggpubr` but couldn't see where this could be achieved.

Comment: I have added a possible solution to what you want. Please check and let me know if that is what you want!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDITED to take OP preference for output into account**

Ahhhh... okay well let me at least save you a bunch of vertical space and neaten things up by overcoming the fact that `rstatix` doesn't honor the order of your factors and `ggpubr` wants its groups as character not factor.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dsub <- diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 10000), ]
dsub <- dsub %>%
   filter(clarity %in% c('VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2'))

dsub <- droplevels(dsub)

dsub_stats <- 
   dsub %>%
   group_by(cut) %>%
   rstatix::wilcox_test(carat~clarity) %>% 
   mutate(group1 = factor(group1, 
                          ordered = TRUE, 
                          levels = c("VS2", "VS1", "VVS2"))) %>%
   arrange(cut, group1) %>% 
   mutate(group1 = as.character(group1)) %>%
   rstatix::add_xy_position(x='cut')

ggpubr::ggboxplot(dsub, x = "cut", y = "carat",
                  color = "clarity",
                  add='jitter') +
   ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(dsub_stats, 
                              label = "p.adj.signif", 
                              tip.length = 0.01)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is closer to what I wanted but I managed to figure it out. See my answer. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer based upon what you had done and to improve it farther

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

dsub <- diamonds[ sample(nrow(diamonds), 10000), ]

dsub <- dsub %>%
  filter(clarity %in% c('VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2'))

dsub_stats <- dsub %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  wilcox_test(carat~clarity) %>% add_xy_position(x='cut')


ggboxplot(dsub, x = "cut", y = "carat", 
          color = "clarity", 
          add='jitter'
) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(dsub_stats, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.01)
```

[image]